# Is it necessary of Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I created a composer business network and successfully deployed in to the fabric network(Single organization) . The next step is deploying to the fabric network(Multiple organizations). I'm not understanding the purpose of deploying to Multiple organizations . Is it necessary to deploy the composer network into fabric Multiple organizations. Can any one help me from this confusion . 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, The OP is asking "Why do I need to deploy to Multi-org fabric network", not **how**.

While it is not ***required*** for you to deploy anything to a multi-organizational fabric network, typically in real-world scenarios you'd be mostly deploying to such a network structure.

Enterprise Blockchain solutions typically are most useful when they are bringing together different organizations which do business together, and though they are co-operating with each other while doing so, they typically don't **trust each other**.

Normally, in a non-blockchain scenario, these organizations would each have their own system of record keeping, and all business transactions would get entered into multiple independent record books. This creates all sorts of delays, dependencies and need for arbitration when one organization's records don't agree with the other organization's records.

The blockchain becomes a single record for all these co-operating but untrusting organizations. All data entered in to the blockchain is first reviewed by all the organizations, and **only after consensus** is it entered into the records.

This kind of setup is only possible using the multi-org network, with each peer hosting it's own peers that **it** trusts to review the transactions and perform consensus. THAT'S WHY  you need this kind of setup in real-world scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The composer multi-org tutorial provides the information needed to understand the operational aspects needed to run a business network in a multi-organisational fabric network. The tutorial can be found here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

From there you will see that defining an endorsement policy (in the case of the tutorial, both organisations have to endorse transactions) that you need to install the business network onto at least 1 of the peers in each organisation (in the case of the multi-org tutorial the business network is installed to all peers in the organisation).

Once installed and the business network started those peers are able to endorse the transaction.

hyperledger fabric is designed to allow multiple different organisations to share a ledger between them. This is a very common use case of hyperledger fabric.